# Select nth-child after Class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So, I have a **ul** element list and I want to select the first 3 **li** elements after **.active** class

```
<ul>
 <li>The #1</li>
 <li>The #2</li>
 <li class="active">The #3</li>
 <li>The #4</li>
 <li>The #5</li>
</ul>
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
ul li.active ~ li:nth-child(n+3)
```

But it does not work.  Anyone can help me out with this?

P.S.: Class **.active** is dynamically changing, so any ul li:nth-child(n+3) will not help.

Comment: this is not about the + selection

Comment: so be more specific ... you said one element initially. By the way you can do it with + ... simply append them 3 times

Comment: yes, sorry for that. I update the question

Comment: nth selectors criteria rely on hierarchy and to a lesser degree tagName. Siblings cannot be targeted via class. What's the problem with using adjacent sibling combinators:+?

Comment: It has to be the first 3 after active? not all after active?

Answer (score 6):

It appears you can not do this using `nth` options on selectors based on your markup and how the hierarchy works.

If you're looking to give the three `li` selectors after the `li.active` selector a red background, you can target them within your css in one call by appending `+ li` as many times as needed, grouping the selectors together, like so:

```css
li.active + li, 
li.active + li + li, 
li.active + li + li + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>The #1</li>
 <li>The #2</li>
 <li class="active">The #3</li>
 <li>The #4</li>
 <li>The #5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's not going to help me, sorry :/

Comment: Can you explain why? You said you wanted the three li's "selected" after the active class li. This achieves that. Can you explain why this won't help?

Comment: @zagzter this is the only way, if you don't like it then you cannot do it

Comment: @zagzter, people have explained why using `nth` doesn't work with this hierarchy. This really is your best solution. I don't believe there is another way to do this unless you use JavaScript or change your markup. What is wrong with doing it this way? Please give me the reason why this doesn't help you. Withholding information isn't going to help you.

Comment: @zagzter did you find a solution?